# signal.alarm() in Python: scheduling multiple alarms

Tags: python, signals, alarm

There is `signal.alarm()` in Python. But it allows only one alarm to be run simultaneously. This may be a problem. (I may want multiple alarms.)

I am thinking of writing a wrapper around this method to make possible multiple alarms schedules simultaneously.

But maybe there is some Python feature or library which already implements this?

Comment: What do you want at the end of the alarm? Terminate the program?

Comment: @dsgdfg I want to terminate a `Popen`-invoked subprocess. Well, now I am going to do it with co-routines instead